# Send/read Any type in Protobuf (C++)

Tags: c++, serialization, network-programming, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a simple online game at the moment, where a few players can play together, with a centralized UDP server. I use **Google Protobuf 3** for (de-)serialization of packets/messages. Currently, **I'm having trouble determining the type of incoming packets on the client side**. How do I do that in **C++**?

On the server side **(Java)**, I can achieve this with this code:

```java
    private Message parseArbitraryPacket(byte[] data) throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {
        Any any = Any.parseFrom(data);

        for (Class<Message> packetType : listeners.keySet())
            if (any.is(packetType))
                return any.unpack(packetType);

        return null;
    }
```

where `listeners` is a `Map` that maps `Message` classes (e.g. `KeepAlive.class`) to the corresponding listeners (e.g. `KeepAliveListener`).

And this is how I sent packets from server **(Java)** to the client:

```java
    public boolean sendPacket(InetAddress targetAddr, Message packet) {
        try {
            byte[] data = Any.pack(packet).toByteArray();
            srv.getUdpServer().send(new DatagramPacket(
                    data, data.length, targetAddr, srv.getConfig().getUdpServerPort()));

            return true; // success
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("Failed to send a {} packet to {}.",
                    packet.getClass().getName(), targetAddr.getHostAddress());
            log.error("Details:", ex);

            return false; // failure
        }
    }
```

where `srv.getUdpServer()` is a `DatagramSocket` — the server itself.

How do I now receive **diiferent** types of packets in my **C++** client (I know how to parse specific types of packets, e.g. that `KeepAlive`, but what if I don't know what type of packet did I receive?)? Is there even that `Any` type as well in **C++**? I can't find it.

> ***P.S.:** I found the `Any` type in Java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450556/how-to-know-which-protobuf-message-the-byte-array-is/50291651#50291651)*

Answer (score 4):

On the C++ side, you can do the following.

Include

```
#include <google/protobuf/any.pb.h>
```

Also the corresponding header file for 'Message' also.

```
google::protobuf::Any any;
    
any.ParseFromString(/* put your byte[] data here */);


Message msg;


if (any.UnpackTo(&msg)
{
    // successfully unpacked to Message type
    // do rest of code here
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "Unknown request type\n";
}
```

Comment: How safe is using Any though? I currently go with a message wrapper with a "one of" inside, which allows me to retrieve packet type for sure (since Protobuf seems to sort of insert packet type/case ID inside every packet sent with this wrapper). That is, it is safe to have packets of same "signature" (containing same field types at same indexes) with "one of", and it's even safe to have multiple empty packets as long as they have a different "one of" case. Since the time I asked this question I realized that Any is way worse in these terms, isn't it?