# Determine correct protobuf class

Tags: c++, c++11, protocol-buffers

In my existing ZeroMQ application am playing to change my payload to google protobuf. During Initial analysis problem I am facing is i will have a multiple proto classes,which can be written to log file also. Now in runtime how do I determine which proto is received. And also later at some point if I read the log file here also I will face the same problem. Is there any solution to this? In both proto2 and proto3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocol Buffer does support multiple class definition. The way you do it is by declaring all the types of classes you have in your [Protocol Format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) file.

In this example we declare two different classes and their properties:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package tutorial;

message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}

message House {
  repeated string owner = 1;
}
```

If you are wailing to use protocol buffer as your standard communication protocols I guess you want to send one of the classes. See the official docs where they explain how to deal with this situation in this [post](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#union).

Another good pattern is to create a unique message (Wrapper) that holds common properties and one of the classes:

```
message WrapperMessage {
    required int64 timestmap = 1;
    oneof data {
        Person person = 2;
        House house = 3;
    }   
}
```

Then before decoding the class you can check which type of class the wrapper holds by calling `HasField`.

Note: Protocol Buffers 3 implements a new feature for this purpose based on the  `FileDescriptorSet` and `Any` property.

Comment: Are extensions  helpful in this case?

Comment: I will personally go for the first solution (because it is more centralized and flexible) in Protocol Buffer 3. If you are starting the project from scratch, just don't use Protocol Buffer 2.

Comment: Proto 3 doesn't have  some features which i want, proto 2 does. Can you give me one more example for first solution. Thanks

Comment: It works perfectly in Protobuf 2. Regarding another example, it's pretty much the same design, so I don't think it will be really helpful. Anyway, in this post you find a discussion about the onof feature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564404/how-to-determine-message-type-in-protobuf-so-that-i-can-use-that-type-parsefrom

Comment: How is the first solution more centralized and flexible in proto 3?i would think it will be same in proto 2 and 3

Comment: It is the same design in both versions. There are no significant differences for most of the cases. Don't worry too much about that, pick the one who matches your platform. @NagarajuSherigar